Does increasing the length of a circuit increase the work done on the charges?
If the force (from electrical field) pushing the charges is always the same, surely increasing the length (of circuit) they travel should increase the total energy transferred due to $W=Fd$, or is this force not constant across the circuit?
If not constant, what causes the force to vary? Intuition suggests if current is constant across the circuit, larger resistance would require a larger force to provide same current.

If I increase the length of the circuit, what happens to the resistance across the stretched wires?

What remains constant is the potential difference (Volts). Longer wires means the field (Volts per meter) is smaller.

@JonCuster but also that the number of electrons being pushed is higher. So total work is the same, but youre right that work per electron is smaller

The power sources we use in circuits typically produce either a fixed potential difference or a fixed current. Not a fixed E field.

Increasing the length of the circuit doesn't increase the distance the charges travel in the same way that increasing the length of a track doesn't increase the distance runners have to go if they're running for 10 minutes at a constant speed.
In reality, increasing the length of a circuit will increase the resistance. This amount will be trivial if there's something else in the circuit (like a light bulb), or non-trivial if it's just the wire.
The force per unit charge for a uniform circuit is $F = \frac{\Delta V}{d}$. So if $W = F d$ then $W = \frac{\Delta V}{d} d$ per unit charge or simply $W = \Delta V$.


Does increasing the length of a circuit increase the work done on the
charges?

Not if the voltage across the length is the same for the longer length. That’s because the voltage is the work required per unit charge, $W/Q$, to move the charge between two points, regardless of the distance between the two points.
Keep in mind the electric field between the two points is the gradient of the voltage between them or, $E=V/d$ if the path is uniform, where $d$ is the path distance between the two points. So the electric field will be less if the distance is greater for the same voltage, making the force it exerts on the charge less. But the work will be the same since the distance over which the force acts is greater.
Bottom line: The work required per unit charge to move the charge between two points is the voltage between the points, regardless of the distance between the two points.
Hope this helps.

Oh right thank you so much, so force adjusts to give the same total energy change, but can I ask why this happens?
